# Windows Schedulded Tasks. Run on startup and restart every sunday evening

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Hi is it possible to setup a schedulded task that runs on windows startup and on every sunday evening it should kill the current process and start it again!?

Comment: You can use the Scheduled Tasks option in Windows, if you want to use a graphical user interface. Or do you need code?

Comment: No I already tried the Scheduled Task option in windows. But dont get it configured the way I want. I cant say repeat every sunday and kill it if it is still running. Im on WinXP

Comment: So you want the program to repeat every sunday, but close itself if it's still running ... when? If it finishes and doesn't close?

Comment: Its starts a minimal tomcat. I need to clean some tmp files and thought it would be the easiest way to delete the tmpdir before server startup. Thats the reason I want to reastart it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
del Path_to_tmpdir\tmpdir
start "sunday_progam" Path_to_tomcat\tomcat.exe
```

You write both these commands in a batch file (a normal .txt will do, then Save As -> file_name**.bat**) then put this file in Startup folder (Start -> Programs -> Startup)

The program should automatically close after it finishes deleting tmpdir.

Comment: And for checking the date, if you could assist me, because I'm not on a Windows system now. Please open a command line terminal and write this `date %1` and tell me the output.

Comment: Its in german. It asks me to enter a date in the format DD-MM-YY

Comment: Do you have access to powershell?

Comment: I'll come back in around 2 hours with an answer to this, because I don't have a Windows system near me.

Comment: You should set your time on the server so that when you call the `date` command it will also print the day of the week, I think you need SO (SO - Sonntag). Tell me when you've succeeded puting the day of the week in the time and please print out an example of the `date` command's output.

Comment: "Aktuelles Datum: 29.03.2012
Geben Sie das neue Datum ein: (TT-MM-JJ)" translated: "Current Date: 29.03.2012, Insert the new date: (DD-MM-YY)"

Comment: I found a bug in my batch file. I can now use a Schedulded Task with options starting every sunday evening or on startup. The batch file stops the server before cleaning the tmpdir and starting it again